# Polling SQL Databases

Tags: mysql, trigger, audit, jdbc

Is there any way to poll for MySQL database changes using JDBC? I need exactly which changes happened (not a simple yes/no).

I tried using a thread which executes every 15 seconds to check whether my database was changed.

The query was directly executed from MySQLworkbench / cli

I need to execute java function, which is not possible in a SQL trigger.

Comment: Oracle can have java in triggers, but I was thinking C or anything that can write to a file or socket on which your Java program was listening. The trigger can tell you the table, the action and the id.  Then you fetch what you need with jdbc. Perhaps tell us something more about the problem you are trying to solve. Immediate synchronization is not necessarily efficient.  The cost may be much higher than synchronizing at intervals.

Comment: Could you use a trigger to record the changes in an MySQL table, then consume those with your JDBC tool? Also, why did the every 15 seconds thread solution not work out (sorry if that's been answered before - if so, it's been removed from the comments).

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to pull changes via SQL. But you can read the binary log (be sure it's enabled) just like MySQL slaves do. So, instead of using JDBC, you'll need to use something like [mysql-binlog-connector-java](https://github.com/shyiko/mysql-binlog-connector-java).

The basic idea is the same for all RDBMSs: you act as a slave and receive the changes. A real slave would apply those changes to have an exact copy of master's data, but actually once you get the changes, you can do whatever you want with them.

However each database implements replication in a different way, so there is no universal tool to do this. If you need to get changes from Oracle, you'll need to find a specific library for that purpose.